# Motion Tracking orientation error "No object to apply orientation on"

Tags: video, tracking, scene

I have tracked a video clip and now need to set the floor and axis orientation, but when I select 3 points and click 'Floor' I get an error - "No object to apply orientation on". What does this error mean and how do I fix it? Thanks!
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I haven't solved this error yet, perhaps it had something to do with the fact that I had already imported an OBJ file and messed around with it a bit... but can't see how that would effect motion tracking. No matter because I opened a new project, tracked the footage again and it all worked fine this time...

Comment: Did you *Solve* the scene? Seting orientation will only work once there is a camera solution

Comment: Yes I did Solve the scene first, I tried re-solving it as well and still didn't change the error. No matter I ended up just re-tracking in a new Blender project file and it worked, for some reason.